# Problems with newpage and pdfpageattr

Tags: page-breaking, rotating

I have a document (`article` class) in which sections of text are interrupted by sideways tables. In order to be able to view the document properly I am using

```
\newpage
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
```

and

```
\newpage
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}
```

to turn the pages in the viewer.

The turning works well however I cannot use `\newpage` after a text section and then rotate using `pdfpageattr` without inserting text inbetween. If I do that all the tables disappear. Here an example of this:

```
\newpage
text I dont Want But Need To But There For Tables to show up!
%************************************************************
% FS Tables
%************************************************************

\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}

%%% Table I: Loan Amount
\begin{sidewaystable}
       \centering
       \caption{Loan Amount - Closest-Saathi to Client km}
       \input{reg_fs_e_sewaloan_amount_iv1}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

I would usually include a minimalist document here but in this case it seems rather complicated because I am importing tables etc. Perhaps we can answer the question this way.

Comment: Does `\clearpage` after `sidewaystable` helps?

Comment: It does. Thank you! What's the logic behind that?

Comment: Have a look at the `pdflscape` package.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `sidewaystable` can float. Since you probably want to allow it to continue to float, here is an outline of how to deal with it, using the fact that `fancyhdr` can treat float-only pages differently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage
    \iffloatpage{\global\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 90}}%
    {\global\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 0}}}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]

  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{here is the caption}
    here is a fake table
  \end{sidewaystable}

\lipsum[4-30]
\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. This assumes that `\pdfpageattr` is normally empty. It would be easy to change the code in order to maintain a constant token list in `\pdfpageattr`. The way you redefined `\pdfpageattr` in the question, by appending to it each time, means that `\pdfpageattr` gets longer with each rotation;
2. This will cause all full-page floats to be rotated, so you'll have to do something more sophisticated if you have a mixture of rotated and non-rotated full-page floats.

Answer (score 3):

Environment `sidewaystable` is similar to `table` a floating environment. LaTeX stores these floating objects some time until it finds a place where it can put them. `\clearpage` forces the pending floating objects to be put on the page.