# Automatic rotation of pages containing sideways tables or figures in PDF output

Tags: rotating

Is it possible to have float-only pages, containing sideways tables or figures produced by the `sidewaystable` or `sidewaysfigure` environments of the `rotating` package, automatically rotated in the PDF output?

This question is related to 3 existing questions:

[Rotate single PDF page when viewing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/rotate-single-pdf-page-when-viewing)

[floating sideways table on a rotated page in pdf-viewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433411/floating-sideways-table-on-a-rotated-page-in-pdf-viewer)

[Problems with newpage and pdfpageattr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71399/problems-with-newpage-and-pdfpageattr)

I've tried the answers given there, based on `\pdfpageattr` and `\afterpage` from the `afterpage` package, with or without `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` from the `etools` package, or even modifying directly the definition of `sidewaystable` say, something like

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{sidewaystable}
  {\@rotfloat{table}%
   \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{/Rotate 90}}
  {\afterpage{\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{/Rotate 0}}%
   \end@rotfloat}
\makeatother
```

Things always end up like in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing several rotated pages]

Namely, not only the page with the actual sideways table is rotated, but also the page where the `sidewaystable` environment appears in the LaTeX source.

Of course, it's always possible to rotate pages manually in the PDF output, but it would be nice to have `sidewaystable` etc. rotate the pages automatically. I'm looking for a solution that only rotates the PDF page where the sideways table or figure is floated to, without otherwise altering the formatting in any way (namely, no use of `\clearpage`, `\pagebreak` or the `landscape` environment).

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on the engine how easy it is. With engines using dvi you can use a `\special`, which is then executed at shipout. luatex has `\latelua` which can be used too. With pdflatex you have to use a \label/ref system to keep track of the right page. A possible implementation is here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/2388.

**\begin{advertisment}**

With the new pdfmanagement of LaTeX which is currently provided as a testphase package you can do this (code updated 2023-10)(depending on the engine it will require two compilations):

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{env/sidewaystable/end}{\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{ThisPage}{Rotate}{90}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{table}[t]
\centering\fbox{xxxxxx}\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\kant[1-5]

\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.8\paperwidth}}
\hline
\kant[1-2]\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{large sideways table}
\end{sidewaystable}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Be aware that it is not compatible with everything, check the document of pdfmanagement-testphase.

**\end{advertisment}**

Comment: Many thanks for the speedy response! Both solutions (the original one here and the one at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472608/2388) work perfectly (except with XeTeX for the latter, but that's really minor, I wasn't planning of using XeTeX for this document anyway). I wasn't aware of the future PDF management capabilities of LaTeX; that's very cool indeed, it seems quite natural given the evolution of document processing. I look forward to seeing this included in standard LaTeX. Thanks again!

Comment: Can we expect the `advertisment` environment, too? But this sounds very nice indeed ....